# i am facing issue to get bat files logs in jenkins pipeline in running time

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have bat file which are executing in windows server. in the bt file the powershell file is executing and redirecting to output file then that file data is not displaying in jenkins in running time.
Here the problem is the output file is printing in console once job is done but not in running time.

```
cmd /c powershell.exe path\sample.ps > output.txt
@echo
type output.txt
@echo
```

Comment: Is that the actual line from you batch file?  Shouldn't "sample.ps" actually be "sample.ps1"?  I have tried executing ps1 code in other extensions, and no success.  Also, 1> is a pipe command, so make sure there is a space between the 1 and >, else batch may get confused.

Comment: Hi Darin, its ps1 only and its running fine there is no issue in getting console.but in the batch file the powershell file is executed and then it redirected to text file. so once the ps1 file executed successfully then only it is redirecting to txt and it is displaying in console. but i need to get display the logs from ps1 whenever it is executing.

Comment: I created a sample.ps1 file with a single "Write-Host" and then created a batch file containing the exact line I see in your question, replacing ps with ps1.  As I expected everything after "output.txt" is ignored.  Maybe you have new lines before the @echo statements and the type statements.  But there are problems with that.  Mainly, the type output.txt` has this backtick at the end that makes no sense.  Could you clarify if the @echo statements are on a line of their own and where is the backtick supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Use [tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

In below example, `running` is printed on console before the script's execution is complete. See timestamps in console output for reference.

Execute shell:

```
cat > script.sh << EOF
echo running | tee log.txt
sleep 30
EOF

chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Jenkins Console Output:

```
17:28:09 + cat
17:28:09 + chmod +x script.sh
17:28:09 + ./script.sh
17:28:09 running
17:28:39 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: is it only for sh files or even can we use it in bat files also

Comment: You can use in batch script too: `powershell "echo running | tee log.txt"`